# Почему возникает ошибка в gulp task?

Tags: gulp, phantomjs

Сделал таск в gulp:

```
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spawn = require("gulp-spawn");


gulp.task('snapshot', function(){
  gulp.src('snapshot.js')
    .pipe(spawn({
      cmd: "phantomjs",
      args: [
        "snapshot.js",
        "http://localhost:3000/#/index/",
        "index"
      ]
    }));
});
```

Этот таск запускает в фантом js файл с парсингом страницы 
Файл фантом:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = system.args[1];
var name = system.args[2]; 

page.open(url, function () {

  fs.write('snapshot/'+name+'.html', page.frameContent, 'w');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Отдельно файл отлично работает, а при запуске через gulp получаю ошибку:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:690:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:709:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:634:40)
    at PassThrough.stream._transform (d:\Project\rts-site\node_modules\gulp-spawn\index.js:84:18)
    at PassThrough.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:179:10)
    at PassThrough.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:167:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:288:5)
    at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:217:11)
    at write (d:\Project\rts-site\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (d:\Project\rts-site\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:632:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (d:\Project\rts-site\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:664:5)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

ПС Мне просто надо запустить файл phantom через gulp. Если можно это сделать другим способом, с удовольствием выслушаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В windows необходимо указывать целиком путь до исполняемого файла, тога таск gulp-а будет выглядеть так:

```
gulp.task('snapshot', function(cb){
    var phantom = spawn('C:/Users/userName/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/p‌​hantom‌​js.exe', [
        'snapshot.js',
        'http://localhost:3000/#/index/',
        'index'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, вам не нужен файловый поток в Gulp задаче. Совсем. Вы вполне можете обойтись традиционным подходом с порождению процессов:

```
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

gulp.task('snapshot', function(cb){
    var phantom = spawn('phantomjs', [
        'snapshot.js',
        'http://localhost:3000/#/index/',
        'index'
    ]);

    phantom.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
        if (code !== 0) {
            return cb(new Error('Exit code is not 0: ' + code));
        }

        cb();
    });
});
```

Comment: К сожалению, тоже появляется ошибка:
`Starting 'snapshot'...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn phantomjs ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:432:11)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: @drm, ошибка `ENOENT` появляется, когда `child_process.spawn` не может найти выполняемую команду. Убедитесь, что команда `phantomjs` может быть вызвана из директории, в которой вы запускаете gulp. А еще стоит проверить переменные окружения и, возможно, использовать абсолютный путь до `phantomjs`

Comment: https://github.com/Drm1804/snaphot.git Выложил файлы сюда, как они у меня есть. Специально вместе с подключенными библиотеками. Вообще файлы лежат в одной директории, и отдельно phantomjs запускается, но ни через gulp ни через node запускаться не хочет

Comment: @drm, все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в вопросе. Ваш код, мне тестить, увы негде. Еще раз: у вас скорее всего есть проблема с запуском, phantomjs. Если это так, то gulp тут ни при чем и не имеет отношения к вопросу. Локализуйте проблему, и задавайте конкретные вопросы

Comment: я все-таки не пойму: у меня все файлы лежат в одной папке. Если я запуская фантом файл из консоли напрямую, то все работает. Если я запускаю фантом файл через задачу gulp, или как дочерний процесс из файла node.js то получаю ошибку. Согласен, что gulp тут не причем. Тогда в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В общем-то Вы были правы. Для windows необходимо было указать путь к файлу целиком. В итоге все заработало.
`gulp.task('snapshot', function(cb){
    var phantom = spawn('C:/Users/userName/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/p‌​hantom‌​js.exe', [
        'snapshot.js',
        'http://localhost:3000/#/index/',
        'index'
    ]);`